# This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

my program has 3 warnings of the following statement:

> This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously.
>   Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls,
>   or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

What is the warning try to tell me? What should I do?

This is my code: Is it running using multi-threading?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task task1 = new Task(Work1);
    Task task2 = new Task(Work2);
    Task task3 = new Task(Work3);

    task1.Start();
    task2.Start();
    task3.Start();

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static async void Work1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("10 started");
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    Console.WriteLine("10 completed");
}

static async void Work2()
{
    Console.WriteLine("3 started");
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    Console.WriteLine("3 completed");
}

static async void Work3()
{
    Console.WriteLine("5 started");
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Console.WriteLine("5 completed");
}
```

Comment: `async` does not mean "multi-threaded". See my [intro to `async`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) post for an explanation of what `async` does.

Comment: @StephenCleary Thanks, the article is very nice and easy for understanding

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `async` keyword, by itself, doesn't really do much. Remove it from your code and your code will act exactly the same.

What does `async` do?

- It changes what's valid inside of the method, specifically it allows you to use the `await` keyword
- In turn, it means that the body of the method will be transformed, based on the `await`s that are present in the body of the method.
- And if the method returns a value, the method is also transformed to wrap the return value in a `Task`.

However, if you a) Don't have any `await`s in your method body and b) are `void` returning, then nothing special will be achieved. The compiler warning does try to be clear about this - an `async` method without any `await`s just plain doesn't make sense. `await`s are the more important part of this feature.

Comment: What if only methods within the body of async method are awaitable, and this async method is also used elsewhere with await, what then? It is maybe better to create a second method with continuation and wrap the async method in it?

Answer (score 9):

If you are overriding an async method with a sync method you can:

```
await Task.Run(() => [YOUR SYNC METHOD]);
```

Answer (score 5):

You have used '`async`' keyword with method which indicates that Work1(),Work2() and Work3() methods are executed asynchronously,but you have not used 'await' keyword.So it executed as synchronously.Use '`await`' keyword if you want to execute it asynchronously.

```
 static async void Work1()
 {
     Console.WriteLine("10 started");
     await Task.Delay(10000);
     Console.WriteLine("10 completed");
 }

 static async void Work2()
 {
     Console.WriteLine("3 started");
     await Task.Delay(3000);
     Console.WriteLine("3 completed");
 }

 static async void Work3()
 {
     Console.WriteLine("5 started");
     await Task.Delay(5000);
     Console.WriteLine("5 completed");
 }
```

Comment: This code will run asynchronously but without awaiting a result.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your code will probably use multi-threading. However, it would still do so if you just removed the `async` keyword. As you did not explain why it's there, I suggest removing it.

If you want an async/await pattern, you can use `Task.Delay()` but I would suggest you read more on async/await before using it:

```
static async void Work3()
{
    Console.WriteLine("5 started");
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    Console.WriteLine("5 completed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You designated your methods (Work1, Work2, Work3) with the keyword `async` but none of your code within those methods uses the `await` operator to invoke asynchronous calls.

Comment: This code will run asynchronously but without awaiting a result.