# *Virtual* method lacks 'await' return value?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, virtual

I have an async virtual method that returns a default boolean that is used in the of some base functionality of my application. i.e. If there is no setup to do, assume it was successful.

I understand the warning method in the context of a *non-virtual* method, but I'm wondering the best way to implement this in a *virtual* method. What should I be returning in the virtual method to ensure this warning is removed? Or should I just ignore?

```cs
// WARNING: This async method lacks 'await'
// virtual is the differentiating factor here
protected virtual async Task<bool> SetupAsync()
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `virtual` has nothing to do with it. You marked your method `async` but you don't have `await` anywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41157449/this-async-method-lacks-await-operators-and-will-run-synchronously)

Comment: I understand, my question specifically calls out the fact that it is a `virtual` method. I cannot override this method to be async when its virtual implementation is non-async. I am asking for the best practice of what to return in the virtual method when I need a default simple bool return.

Comment: The overriding method doesn't have to be `async`, just awaitable. Remove `async` and return `Task.FromResult(true)`.

Comment: So `protected virtual Task<bool> SetupAsync()` will not need any overridden methods to have `async` in their signature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I understand you are creating a class that you expect to be overridden, and you want to provide a default implementation for `SetupAsync()` which allows an overridden version to be `async`.

The `async` keyword is not part of the method signature that must be copied for a method to be overridden. Only the return type, parameters and access modifier.

If there is no asynchronous code in your method, then don't use `async`. If you want to allow an overridden version to be `async`, then all you need to do is make it return a `Task`.

In your default implementation (which runs synchronously), you just return a value in a `Task` using [`Task.FromResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult).

For example:

```
class Test {
    protected virtual Task<bool> SetupAsync() {
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}

class Test2 : Test {
    protected override async Task<bool> SetupAsync() {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Overriding a method isn't about the inner workings of the method, it's about how it is exposed to other code. Any code must be able to call an overridden method in the same way as it would the default implementation, and the `async` keyword itself doesn't have anything to do with that.

The `async` keyword just enables the use of `await` *inside the method*. It's true that using the `async` keyword requires the method to return a `Task`, but the fact that it's *returning a `Task`* is what changes how other code interacts with it.

Comment: Thank you, this exactly describes my use case. The selective nature of what is included in the overridden signatures is... interesting...

Comment: I added a little extra to my answer to hopefully explain that "selective nature".

Comment: Great, I was aware of using `async` enabling the use of `await`, the disconnect of my understanding was: If I don't have async in the `virtual` signature, I'll lose the ability to use await in the overridden method.